# How to use MATLAB to send signals to a port of an IP address?

Tags: matlab, port, tcp

How to use MATLAB to send signals to a port of an IP address?

The fact is that I have connected a robot car with PC by Wifi and I've decided that the signal `FF000400FF` received by the robot will drive the car forward. I tested this by TCP＆UDP tools and it was OK. So I think it should have been OK using MATLAB to send this signal, too.

my code is:

```
t = tcpip('192.168.1.1',2001);
fopen(t);
a=dec2hex(1095216922879);  %FF000400FF(H)
fprintf(t,a)
```

but it doesn't work. I've been working on this for long but failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that "it doesn't work" is never sufficient information. Is there an error? Does anything happen? What happens instead of the expected behaviour?

Comment: No error is reported by the MATLAB.But the robot-car just doesn't move.So I wonder if the signal has been sent.And I use a TCP tool to catch bag sent from the PC.It caught nothing.So maybe there is something wrong with the code?or the MATLAB?THANKS!

Comment: What data type is your robot expecting? Is it really expecting string data?

Comment: Since you didn't see anything transferred from the PC: are you sure the IP and the port are OK in the first place?

Comment: 1.Actually the robot is only able to read hexadecimal data, like FF000400FF. But in the code I transform it into a denary data due to the "fprintf" function. I'm not quite sure if MATLAB has any insturctions or functions that could send a hexadecimal data directly to a IP port?

Comment: 2.I think it's ok to read a string data,since I directly send "FF000400FF" to robot by TCP-IP path.it works.

Comment: 3.the IP and the port are OK , because it's all fine if I use other tools except MATLAB... so I feel puzzled . is the MATLAB cannot send a hexadecimal data ?

Comment: Have you connected wireshark, or similar, to view the raw packets? This should help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @zelanix [No](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip.html)

Comment: @Yancy do you have the Instrument Control Toolbox?

Comment: What do you mean by *the robot is only able to read hexadecimal data*? Does this *really* mean a number encoded as a hexadecimal string? Hex is usually only a way of representing numeric data for human readability. Again, connect wireshark and compare what is being sent to what is being sent from the other tools that work.

Comment: I think you should use `fwrite(tcpip_object,value)` instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: @excaza I'm pretty sure it would throw an error otherwise.

Comment: I agrees with @NKN. When you say your robot takes hexadecimal data as input, for me it means it is expecting binary values, probably sequences of bytes, which are commonly represented as hexadecimal strings for us human ... but most microcontrollers prefers good old binary bytes. So as NKN says, try `fwrite` instead of `fprintf`. (also try to send your bytes sequencially, so you have control over the endianness (which is quite often reversed between most PC/Mac and embedded microcontrollers).

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
fwrite(t, [255, 0, 4, 0, 255])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myhost = java.net.InetSocketAddress('192.168.1.1',2001);
mysoc = java.net.Socket();
mysoc.connect(myhost, 2000); % Two second timeout
connected=mysoc.isConnected();
if connected
    mystream = mysoc.getOutputStream();
    mystream.write(hex2dec('FF000400FF'));
    mystream.flush();
    mystream.close();
end

mysoc.close();
```

You can wrap this in a try catch block:

```
try
...
catch ME
    if (isa(ME, 'matlab.exception.JavaException'))
       reason = class(ME.ExceptionObject);
       connected = 0;
    end
end
```

This should work on any platform, desktop or deployed. If your car returns something in response to the command, you could read it with an inputStream. Best of all, you can post the text in reason if "it doesn't work"!